# Display controller variable on VF page. How?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, lightning-design-system

I am trying to show 3 consecutive "blocks/span", 2 are variables, 3rd is a button.

Links to : [1. the element](http://codepad.org/rubn5s1g) 2. [the controller](http://codepad.org/1TuyO2py)

WITH the last button element, the page DOES NOT save, the error given is :

> Error: Could not resolve the entity from `<apex:outputField>` value binding '{!totalGoodBC}'. `<apex:outputField>` can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.

WITHOUT the button, the page SAVES, the error is :

> value for `<apex:outputField>` is not a dynamic binding

What is going on here?

Comment: This would be a better question if the relevant parts of the code were pasted in here.

Comment: I already did. Kindly check the 2nd line, it has the links to the relevant controller and element code.

Comment: Yes, I see the links.  Inline is generally preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this scenario, you should use `<apex:outputText>` instead of `<apex:outputField>`.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!totalGoodBC}" styleClass="slds-input"/>
```

`<apex:outputField>`is used to bind values which are of `Sobject` type. Or in other words, instance of [Sobject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) class.

Comment: Perfect :) So I should use outputTEXT for non-SObj variables and outputFIELD only for SObj vars?

Comment: @fraglord you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the text to be passed:

public class Sample {
    public String strText {get;set;}
    public Sample() {
    }

```
public PageReference nextPage() {
    PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/NextPage');
    pg.getParameters().put('str', strText);
    pg.setRedirect(false);
    return pg;
}
```

}

Second VF Page:

Value passed in previous page is {!strText}

public class NextPageController {
    public String strText {get;set;}
    public NextPageController() {
        strText = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('str');
    }
}
Iam Not Understand Iur Question Can U go to This Link U getting More Info How To Create Custom Button And Standerd Button In VF Pages http://www.infallibletechie.com/search/label/Apex%20and%20Visualforce

Comment: Ah, but I'm not trying to go to the next page. Also, what does getParameters() do?